# N gram NLP to Excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, nlp, export-to-csv

I am struggling with this piece of code . I need to create a 1 and 2 gram model and map the grams with their frequency;  After I need to write the 2 models to one EXCEL file in two different sheets..
I come to here displaying the 2 model gram and frequency but struggling on on how to append the outcome and create the excel file.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
f = open('data.json','r')
raw = f.read()

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)

#Create your bigrams
bgs = nltk.bigrams(tokens)

#compute frequency distribution for all the bigrams in the text
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bgs)
for k,v in fdist.items():
print (k,v)
```

Thank you

Comment: To clarify, your question is on how to export the output to an Excel file, correct?

Comment: Yes it is to export the output of two models (one gram and bigram) into 2 different sheets of the excel file

Answer (score 1):

This code will export the frequence distribution in a csv file. :

```
import csv
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
f = open('data.json','r')
raw = f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)

#Create your bigrams
bgs = nltk.bigrams(tokens)

#compute frequency distribution for all the bigrams in the text
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bgs)
with open("fdist.csv", "w") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(fdist.items())
```

Comment: I have this traceback 
    writer.writerows(fdist.items())
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: change "wb" by "w" and tell me